# I want to change the color of some letters of post title

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I have two types of posts in Wordpress Platform. Some are named as "Premium Content" for registered members and others are general posts. Now every premium content post has the Words "Premium Content" in the title, so I want to make these two words "Premium Content" with a separate color. I have attached an image for the better understanding.

[image]

But how can I do this ? Any help will be great for me. Thanks.

Comment: `var newStr = str.replace(/Premium Content/, "<span>$&</span>");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have jQuery:

```
$('a:contains("Premium Content")').html(function(i,h){
    return h.replace('Premium Content', '<span class="premiumContent">Premium Content</span>');
});
```

Coupled with the CSS:

```
a span.premiumContent {
    color: #0f0;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/mNar7/).

References:

- [`:contains()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/).
- [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/).

Comment: Thanks for this. I have seen the fiddle. I am asking for this exactly. I am trying this and I think it will help me.

Comment: You're very welcome indeed!

Comment: Easy and clean, nice one David

Answer (score 0):

```
<h2>
  <a href="#">
     <span class="premium">PREMIUM CONTENT</span> Rest of the title here.
  </a>
</h2>
```

And in CSS:

```
.premium {
  color: #FD0000;
}
```

Comment: I can't add this HTML.